An alternative solution to the equation $\sqrt{\sqrt{x+2}+\sqrt{x-2}}=2\sqrt{\sqrt{x+2}-\sqrt{x-2}}+\sqrt{2}$

Solve the equation
$$\sqrt{\sqrt{x+2}+\sqrt{x-2}}=2\sqrt{\sqrt{x+2}-\sqrt{x-2}}+\sqrt{2}$$

I know how to solve this equation using double substitution $\sqrt{x+2}=a$, $\sqrt{x-2}=b$. But I want to understand how I can solve using hyperbolic substitution, for example, when I do the substitution $\sqrt{x+2}=\sinh t$, $\sqrt{x-2}=\cosh t$, then it turns out to be infinite number of solutions with a period, and a very ugly and scary answer
Is it possible to solve this equation using hyperbolic substitution?

You cannot do  the substitution $\sqrt{x+2}=\sinh t,\sqrt{x-2}=\cosh t$ because $\cosh^2-\sinh^2=1$. Instead, do $\sqrt{x+2}=2\cosh t,\sqrt{x-2}=2\sinh t$.

@user2661923 No you cannot, because on the RHS the two things are being subtracted inside the radical, not added.

set up to use the (8, 15, 17)  Pythagorean triple.  Pretty good deleted answer, the product of the two slightly different square roots is just 2.

You need to be slightly more careful with the hyperbolic substitution.

Unlike their trigonometric counterparts, hyperbolic sines and cosines come with a built-in order, to wit $\cosh t > \sinh t$. Accordingly you should be prepared to set $\sqrt{x+2}$ to the hyperbolic cosine function and $\sqrt{x-2}$ to the hyperbolic sine function.

The hyperbolic functions have the identity $\cosh ^2t-\sinh^2t=1$, but the radicands differ by $4$. To balance this and respect the first point above you should render


$\sqrt{x+2}=2\cosh t, \sqrt{x-2}=2\sinh t$
With these substitutions you should get an equation that can be rendered as a quadratic in $y=\exp(t/2)$ (remember that $\cosh t+\sinh t =\exp(t)$ and $\cosh t-\sinh t=\exp(-t)$). Continue from there.
